# Example of a continuous surjection from $I=[a,b], a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ to $S^2$.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Continuous surjection from $I=[a,b], a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ to $S^2$.

What is an example of such a surjection? I can't think of any. I would greatly appreciate any examples.

Comment: I expect that a similar construction to the Peano space filling curve would work.

Comment: Also, using a classical theorem: every Peano continuum (compact metrisable connected and locally connected space) is the continuous image of a closed interval (and is thus path-connected too).

Comment: Once you have the Peano continuum $[0,1] \mapsto [0,1] \times [0,1]$, the rest is easy, by composing with any continuous surjection $[0,1] \times [0,1] \to S^2$.